# Example of maximal monotone operators in non-reflexive Banach spaces with applications in PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, monotone-operator-theory

My question is about examples of maximal monotone operators that are defined in **non-reflexive** Banach spaces and have applications in PDEs, variational inequalities, etc (any application actually)?

If possible I would like to exclude the convex subdifferential since it is a well-known example.

Answer (score 3):

Take the minimizers of the energy functional
$$
E(u) = \int_\Omega \frac12 |\nabla u|^2 + fu + |u| dx, \quad u\in H^1_0(\Omega).
$$
The solution $u$ fulfills the variational inequality
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot (\nabla v-\nabla u) + fu  + |v|-|u|dx \ge 0 \quad \forall v\in H^1_0(\Omega),
$$
which can be written as a differential inclusion
$$
-\Delta u + f + \lambda =0, \ \lambda \in\partial \|\cdot\|_1(u).
$$
Here, the subdifferential of the $L^1$-norm is a maximal monotone operator from $L^1$ to $L^\infty$.

---

Another example is the following minimization problem
$$
\min I_C(|\nabla u|) + \int_\Omega uf dx,
$$
where $I_C$ is the indicator function of the $L^\infty$-unit ball.
This leads to the infinity-Laplace equation (think $p$-Laplace with $p\to\infty$).

Comment: Of course any subdifferential is maximal monotone and is involved in variational inequalities (in any Banach space). What about examples that do not depend on the subdifferential?